# How to debug systemd "init" freeze during boot?

Tags: boot, systemd, init-script, initramfs

I'm trying to get my own `init` script running on [some ARM hardware](http://www.acmesystems.it/terra) and Debian Jessie with systemd. The overall boot concept and `init` script is almost identical to a x86 variant, which works fine. For both hardwares the whole SD card image is pre-built on a x86 host.

When running on the ARM hardware, having **serial console access** I see that my `init` script runs fine up to the point where `switch_root` is called:

`exec switch_root -c /dev/console /newroot /sbin/init`

Nothing happens after that. No error message is printed - which makes it difficult to find the problem.

The kernel command line is...

`ro root=LABEL=IM_BOOT1 panic=10 mem=256M console=ttyS0,115200 systemd.log_level=debug`

...and AFAIK this should make `systemd` print maximum debug messages. Unfortunately nothing is printed.

**Any idea/hint what I could do to understand what could be causing the freeze, or with other words - understand what is going on?**

---

The only strange detail are some warnings in the kernel log *before* calling `switch_root`:

`<snip>
ext4: Unknown symbol jbd2_journal_errno (err 0)
ext4: Unknown symbol jbd2_journal_begin_ordered_truncate (err 0)
ext4: Unknown symbol jbd2_journal_flush (err 0)
ext4: Unknown symbol mb_cache_entry_find_next (err 0)
squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
aufs 3.16-20150928
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_output_report (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hidinput_count_leds (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_allocate_device (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_destroy_device (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_alloc_report_buf (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_set_field (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_check_keys_pressed (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_input_report (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_debug (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol __hid_request (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_parse_report (err 0)
usbhid: Unknown symbol hid_add_device (err 0)
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_report_device_reset (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_remove_host (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_report_bus_reset (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_sense_desc_find (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_eh_prep_cmnd (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_host_put (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_scan_host (err 0)
usb_storage: Unknown symbol scsi_is_host_device (err 0)
<snip>`

...however these modules *appear* to work fine anyway. I don't know if that is related.

Some additional details:

- Debian installation is prepared using `debootstrap` (same method works perfectly with x86)
- Custom built Kernel: `Linux (none) 3.16.7 #1 Mon Nov 16 08:32:55 UTC 2015 armv5tejl GNU/Linux`, patched with AUFS and hardware-specific device tree
- both Kernel and root fs are built with help of QEMU on a x86 host
- `initramfs` boots with **BusyBox**, sets up the AUFS final root fs and finally invokes `switch_root`. The same method (nearly 100% identical `init` script) works fine on x86
- I can run an interactive shell just before running `switch_root` and I can't find anything that isn't working as expected at that point

Comment: Cool toy. I am myself running here an ARM lamobo R1.Does it seems something should be compiled in the kernel not as module, or am I with the wrong impression? Try the armbian forum, it seems the guys have tried to make systemd work.

Comment: What makes you think modules are missing? At least in the `/newroot` environment there should be all modules. There aren't all modules in the initramfs, though, however enough for my `init` script to run fine. BTW, the HW manufacturer provides a Debian Jessie image w/ systemd, but they are booting from the second partition directly, without an initramfs. BTW, Lamobo R1 looks interesting.

Comment: The errors. But I have not dealt with kernel full compilations for a long time in Linux. Lamobo R1 is very interesting, internal switch a boon, pity the wifi is braindead. The HW manufacturer also provides Bananian and openwrt, which are too sloppy hacked for my taste. I prefer so much the work the armbian guys have done.

Comment: Tried with a RAMdisk that includes *all* Kernel modules (19 MB compressed), however the same warnings keep appearing in Kernel log and `systemd` still freezes... :-( Any idea whatsoever?

Comment: Besides one last try about compiling a kernel with them instead of using them as modules, not really.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Kernel was missing some important settings, that are required by `systemd`.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/README shows what Kernel config settings were necessary.

Once configured, `systemd` started working immediately.